# How to distinguish manual sharing and apex sharing in code level

Tags: apex-sharing

I would like to distingish sharing between manual sharing and apex sharing

For example please check below code:

***Code snippet***

```
List<Document__Share> lstDocSharesDelete1 = [select Id,UserOrGroupId,RowCause from Document__Share where ParentId in:docId and (RowCause!='Owner')];
        for(Document__Share dc:lstDocSharesDelete1){
            if(String.valueOf(dc.UserOrGroupId.getSObjectType())=='Group' && dc.RowCause=='Manual'){
                lstDocShare.add(dc);
            }
        }
```

Here I'am checking dc.RowCause=='Manual'in code level,If I do share the record manually also it becomes true.

So How Can I distinguish it?

Comment: For custom objects you can define a rowcause for apex sharing. For standard object you are SOL

Comment: Give this a try: `dc.RowCause== Schema.Document__Share.RowCause.Manual`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Custom Sharing Reasons are only available for custom objects. For standard objects, the only Row Cause you can use is Manual in Apex, so there is no way to see the difference between 'user manual' sharing and apex sharing the standard Document object you are using.

See the documentation:

> Apex sharing reasons and Apex managed sharing recalculation are only
>   available for custom objects.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm